# How can I retain the test report of multiple gradle test tasks within the same job on GitLab?

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, continuous-integration, gitlab

This is what my .yml file looks like:

```
image: openjdk:11

variables:
  GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

build_custom_scripts:
  script:
    - ./gradlew test --tests=MainTest.testIsOddNumber
    - ./gradlew test --tests=MainTest.testIsInAlphabeticalOrder
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - build/test-results/test/TEST-*.xml
    reports:
      junit: build/test-results/test/TEST-*.xml
```

Currently, in the test report, I only see the second test. Obviously the file is overwritten for the second gradlew test task. but I want to retain the content of the report from the previous test task. how do I do that? Before someone suggests it: I've already checked the gitlab docs about unit test reports and read a lot of threads on gitlab, but it didn't help.

EDIT: I don't want to execute multiple unit tests with one gradlew test command, which I know is possible. I am specifically asking about the junit reports of multiple gradlew test tasks being executed within the same job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `artifacts` keyword does have a `name` [option](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactsname), but that affects all the artifacts when they're downloaded, not when they're uploaded. There aren't any other options in the `artifacts` keyword, so it doesn't look like there's a way to tell the runner to not overwrite them, however you can solve it in the `script` section by simply moving the file to a new name:

```yaml
... # this part above is all the same
build_custom_script:
  script:
    - ./gradlew test --tests=MainTest.testIsOddNumber
    - mv build/test-results/test/{filename}.xml build/test-results/test/testIsOddNumber.xml
    - ./gradlew test --tests=MainTest.testIsInAlphabeticalOrder
    - mv build/test-results/test/{filename}.xml build/test-results/test/testIsInAlphabeticalOrder.xml
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - build/test-results/test/testIsOddNumber.xml
      - build/test-results/test/testIsInAlphabeticalOrder.xml
...
```

It's certainly not ideal if you have a lot of these, but unless there's a way to run them all at once and have the report cover them all (I'm not familiar with gradle), doing something like this should work.

For the junit report, you can specify multiple .xml files and Gitlab will combine them when it displays them in the UI:

```
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit: build/test-results/test/testIsOddNumber.xml, build/test-results/test/testIsInAlphabeticalOrder.xml]
```

So you can rename them so you can upload them individually for review later, but still get them all to show up in the junit report, or like you had before, for the junit report you can use wildcards like `build/test-results/test/*.xml` and it will work the same way. When uploading them as regular artifacts though they would each need a unique name, or you could tar them together `tar czf build/test-results/test/*.xml test-results.tar.gz` and then upload the tar file.

Here's the details about the [junit report](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#artifactsreportsjunit)

Comment: ok that comes relatively close to what l had in mind. is there a way to copy the content of the report in  junit: build/test-results/test/TEST-*.xml to another file like you did above?

Comment: Just found something in the docs that will help, I'll update my answer.